# What are the back stories behind the two halves of the Brady Bunch family?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-brady-bunch

Is there a back story to:

> Here's the story of a lovely lady
>   Who was bringing up three very lovely girls
>   All of them had hair of gold, like their mother
>   The youngest one in curls
>
> Here's the story of a man named Brady
>   Who was busy with three boys of his own
>   They were four men living all together
>   Yet they were all alone

Why were they all alone? Death in a war? Irreconcilable differences in former marriage(s)?

Is there a back story?